# SQLite Join Table from Subquery

Tags: android, database, sqlite, join, subquery

I have the following scheme in a SQLite table (TABLE 1):

```
ID          NAME
---------------------------------
1           "NAME 1"
2           "NAME 2"
...         ...
```

The Id from the table is a foreign key in another table like this one (TABLE 2):

```
ID           NAME            DEPARTMENT (FROM TABLE 1)
------------------------------------------------------------
1            "PRODUCT 1"     2
2            "PRODUCT 2"     2
3            "PRODUCT 3"     1
```

I need to return a query with all of the elements in the TABLE 1 and with a new column named "PRODUCTS" which is the count of all the entries in Table 2 where the Department = Table1.ID.

The result would look like this

```
ID         NAME          ENTRIES
---------------------------------------------
1          "NAME 1"      1 (SELECT COUNT FROM TABLE 2 WHERE DEPARTMENT = 1)
2          "NAME 2"      2 (SELECT COUNT FROM TABLE 2 WHERE DEPARTMENT = 2)
```

I don't know how to do this in SQLite. Is it possible? How could the query would have to be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Table2
        WHERE Department = Table1.ID
       ) AS Entries
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: This is a simpler approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Join against the second table and group by the first table columns.
When you group your result then aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group and not the complete result set.

```
select t1.id, t1.name, count(t2.id) as entries
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.department
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: Do I need to overwrite the tables names or you just did it because it would be easier to write?

Comment: I just did it to make it shorter